# Selecting multiple values/aggregators from Influxdb, excluding time

Tags: grafana, influxdb

I got a influx db table consisting of

```
> SELECT * FROM results
name: results
time                artnum   duration 
----                ------   --------   
1539084104865933709 1234     34  
1539084151822395648 1234     81  
1539084449707598963 2345     56  
1539084449707598123 2345     52
```

and other tags. Both `artnum` and `duration` are fields (that is changeable though). I'm now trying to create a query (to use in grafana) that gives me the following result with a calculated `mean()` and the number of measurements for that `artnum`:

```
artnum   mean_duration  no. measurements
------   --------       -----  
1234     58             2
2345     54             2
```

First of all: Is it possible to exclude the `time` column? Secondly, what is the influx db way to create such a table? I started with

```
SELECT mean("duration"), "artnum" FROM "results"
```

resulting in `ERR: mixing aggregate and non-aggregate queries is not supported`. Then I found https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.6/guides/downsampling_and_retention/, which looked like what I wanted to do. I then created a infinite retention policy (duration 0s) and a continuous query

```
> CREATE CONTINUOUS QUERY "cq" ON "test" BEGIN 
SELECT mean("duration"),"artnum"
INTO infinite.mean_duration 
FROM infinite.test 
GROUP BY time(1m) 
END
```

I followed the instructions, but after I fed some data to the db and waited for 1m, `SELECT * FROM "infinite"."mean_duration" did not return anything.

Is that approach the right one or should I continue somewhere else? The very goal is to see the updated table in grafana, refreshing once a minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

InfluxDB is a **time** series database, so you really need the time dimension - also in the response. You will have a hard time with Grafana if your query returns non time series data. So don't try to remove `time` from the query. Better option is to hide time in the Grafana table panel - use [column styles](http://docs.grafana.org/features/panels/table_panel/#column-styles) and set `Type: Hidden`.

InfluxDB doesn't have a tables, but measurements. I guess you need query with proper [grouping](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.6/query_language/data_exploration/#the-group-by-clause) only, no advance continous queries, etc.. Try and improve this query*:

```
SELECT 
  MEAN("duration"), 
  COUNT("duration") 
FROM results
  GROUP BY "artnum" fill(null)
```

*you may have a problem with grouping in your case, because `artnum` is InfluxDB `field` - better option is to save `artnum` as InfluxDB `tag`.